# Show that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge 35$ if $x+3y+5z \ge 35.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Show that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge 35$ if $x+3y+5z \ge 35.$

I have tried everything (proof by contradiction, etc.) but I can't seem to get it. The book didn't give any constraints whatsoever. Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: $(1^2+3^2+5^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)\ge (x+3y+5z)^2$

Comment: @QuangHoang How about posting an answer, instead of the comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an elegant solution using Cauchy Schwarz already in comments.  Another way using AM-GM:

$$x^2+1^2 \geqslant 2x, \quad y^2+3^2 \geqslant 6y, \quad z^2+5^2 \geqslant 10 z$$
$$\implies x^2+y^2+z^2+(1+9+25) \geqslant 2(x+3y+5z)$$ 
$$\implies x^2+y^2+z^2 \geqslant 35$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured it was going to use AM-GM but I didn't know how to start.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a solution for who know Lagrange multiplier.

Let $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$, and $g(x,y,z)=x+3y+5z=a\ge 35$. Then
\begin{align}
\nabla f(x,y,z)&=(2x,2y,2z)\\
\nabla g(x,y,z)&=(1,3,5)\ne \mathbf{0}
\end{align}
Let $\lambda$ be a real number such that $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$, then
$$
2x=\lambda,\quad 2y=3\lambda,\quad 2z=5\lambda.
$$
Thus
$$
x+3y+5z=\frac{\lambda}{2}+\frac{9\lambda}{2}+\frac{25\lambda}{2}=\frac{35\lambda}{2},
$$
so $\lambda=\frac{2a}{35}$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2+z^2&=\frac{\lambda^2}{4}+\frac{9\lambda^2}{4}+\frac{25\lambda^2}{4}\\
&= \frac{35}{4}\cdot \lambda^2\\
&=\frac{35}{4}\cdot \frac{4a^2}{35^2}\\
&=\frac{a^2}{35}\\
&\ge 35.
\end{align}